# User location sender app crashes when button is pushed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have developed an app that sends the user's location via SMS.  When I starting building it there were no errors, but when it is being tested with an actual phone it crashes ... It would not open.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText phone;
Button emergency;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    phone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

    emergency= (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergency);

    emergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GPStracker g = new GPStracker(getApplicationContext());
            Location l = g.getLocation();
            if (l != null) {
                double lat = l.getLatitude();
                double lon = l.getLongitude();
                String message = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + "," + lon;
                String number = "number";
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
                smsBody.append(Uri.parse(message));
                android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

AND ALSO HERE IS MY CLASS FOR GPS TRACKING

```
public class GPStracker implements LocationListener {
    Context context;
    public GPStracker(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled){
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,10,this);
            Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            return l;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Please enable GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", false);

    }
}
```

AND MY MANIFEST  FILE

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.research.sos.smshelpcaller">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I ALREADY TRY EVERYTHING BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT IS WRONG IN MY CODES OR IS THERE SOMETHING MISSING.

LASTLY HERE IS THE LOGS IN LOGCAT

```
04-03 13:55:56.472 31224-31224/com.research.sos.smshelpcaller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.research.sos.smshelpcaller, PID: 31224
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:1430)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:320)
    at com.research.sos.smshelpcaller.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5052)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20162)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: could you add the error logs from console?

Comment: First of all, PLEASE DON'T SHOUT! Second of all, it's highly unlikely that you will get a log with no error.

Comment: First of all, please do not use all-capital letters. Second - please check adb log for more information.

Comment: why you change your question? first you post different logcat and now again change it.

Comment: You edited your question, changed the original log output, and the question now points to totally different issue. You should look for the answer first - maybe someone already had the same problem. The error you have now does not correspond to original issue you had.

Comment: actually someone commented a code such as this setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); after i enter it the app don''t crash upon opening but if i try to push the button it crashes again giving this logs above

Comment: @JaysonCa-ong you should ask different question. dont changed original question becoz I gave you answer setContentView and some onw point to negative answer.

Comment: sorry man... but your code actually helped ... but now this is the problem

Comment: okay... let me check

Comment: @AnujZunjarrao i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your layout file,
Give your xml reference to activity after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);.

for example..

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: it made some changes but when i try the button it crashes again

Answer (score -1):

According to your log you try to invoke method on Null Pointer:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.research.sos.smshelpcaller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
```

It means, that the code below does not resolve the `R.id.emergency` asset. It simply can't find it and the first line is set to null:

```
emergency= (Button) findViewById(R.id.emergency);
emergency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}
```

You should check if the name of the button you try to use is correct, if there is no spell mistakes, or even if the resource file (for example xml with view) exists.

Comment: i edited the log cat above ... and thats the latest error